# File modified without checking is not lableled as modified in p4v workspace

Tags: perforce

I made changes to a file directly from the file structure without checking it out from perforce, and while the textual changes show up if I open the file from the Perforce client, the file is not marked as modified (in the P4V workspace). Is this normal?

Answer (score 2):

One of the reasons P4 is so speedy is that it's not constantly checking to see if you made changes without its knowledge.

Right-click on the directory from within P4V and choose "Reconcile Offline Work..." and it will check to see the current status and provide you with any relevant options (in this case, pointing out the file to check out as well as displaying that it has been modified).